# Generating text based GUIs in linux

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

I see this type of menu all the time when I configure things through the command line in Linux environments:
[image]

I see that of GUI system while installing things through `apt-get`, I've seen it while booting up, and I've definitely seen it before while configuring programs. I don't just mean a text-based thing where you select with arrow keys, I'm talking about menus that look and work exactly the same as the one you get with `raspi-config` (for example).

Is there some sort of shell command system to generate these menus or something like that, or is it just a coincidence all these programs look like this because someone came up with some sort of C++ trick to do so that some other people also liked and ended up using? I've been wondering for a while now about these menus and I think it would be cool if I could implement this sort of functionality somehow into some of my stuff.

Comment: That is actually an implementation based on `whiptail`: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-use-whiptail-to-write-interactive-shell-scripts/ . At first glance I thought it was `ncurses`, a very common package for terminal guis.

Comment: that looks like the one. Thanks!

Comment: `dialog` is another one, similar to `whiptail` - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64627/whiptail-or-dialog

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Okay I'll post in Unix & Linux next time @jww. Not really sure what you mean about not programming/off topic though because the link provided says it's ok to ask for suggestions about what libraries to use and stuff

Comment: @LAX1DUDE - As far as I know, that area has been off-topic for several years. Checkout [Where can I ask about “finding a tool, library or favorite off-site resource?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251134/608639) on Meta. If its any consolation, I think its a good question; and the policy has frustrated me, too. Also see [How to request book recommendations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113678/173448).